# iOS RXSwift What is the equivalent of debounce which lets through first event only?

Tags: swift4, ios11, rx-swift, throttling, debouncing

I have a button which sends network requests. I want to ignore double taps within this button. I tried `.throttle`, but that didn't seem to work. So I'm trying `.debounce` - this indeed ignores duplicate taps, but only lets through the last event.

What I want is: On first tap, send a network request, ignore subsequent taps within 0.33 seconds.

**Which RXSwift operator would help me put an event through and disable subsequent events within a time window?**

```
let buttonPressObservable = button.rx.tap.asObservable()

buttonPressObservable.debounce(0.33, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.map{/*do stuff*/}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 4.2 of the library, `throttle` has a parameter `latest` that is set to `true` by default. If you set that to false, I think it will give you the behavior you want.